# WCF - Wsdl.exe generated class - Service timeout

Tags: wcf, web-services

I've created a WCF service project. Using the standard generated example service the project generates I create a wrapper class using wsdl.exe.

However the service times out when I use the following code:

```
        Service1 svc = new Service1();
        svc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        svc.Url = "http://localhost:16218/Service1.svc?wsdl";
        string x = svc.GetData(1, true);
```

When I invoke the same webmethod via a normal Service Reference it works fine. What am i missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to call the service, you shouldn't be connecting to the WSDL endpoint!

```
    svc.Url = "http://localhost:16218/Service1.svc?wsdl";
```

Use this code instead:

```
Service1 svc = new Service1();
svc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
svc.Url = "http://localhost:16218/Service1.svc";
string x = svc.GetData(1, true);
```

But why would you use `wsdl.exe` to create a client side bits for WCF?? Use `svcutil.exe` instead! That's the right tool for the WCF job.